# Remove values below a given value with GDAL for DEM geo tif files

Tags: gdal

I have a DEM in GeoTiff format. The processing have made areas that have really low values that I would like to remove.

Are there any GDAL tools that could set all values below -30 to NODATA or -30.

Comment: I've seen this question before... I think the easiest way is in QGIS raster calculator.

Comment: It can be done in GDAL independent of QGIS using calc.py. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can use the No Data value in gdal_translate

```
-a_nodata value:
```

Assign a specified nodata value to output bands. Starting with GDAL 1.8.0, can be set to none to avoid setting a nodata value to the output file if one exists for the source file.

or in gdal_cac.py use the less than (<) or greater than (>) or equals (=) commands.

For example, below will convert the values below 3 to 0 and above 3 to 1. You can use equals as well.

```
gdal_calc.py -A C:temp\raster.tif --outfile=result.tiff --calc="0*(A<3)" --calc="1*(A>3)"
```

so as written by Michael yours would be along the lines of

`gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A*(A>-30)" --NoDataValue=-30`

Or a combination of above.

Comment: Can you use gdal_calc to set a constant for less than and then the original value in the raster for greater than?

Comment: The last example seems to do just that http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html *gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A*(A>-30)" --NoDataValue=-30* thanks! I'll definitely be using that in the future.

Comment: Yes it does sir, it seems underused to me as I have posted a similar answer on this board a few times.

Comment: when i run the above code in my windows terminal, i get prompted to open it "gdal_cal.py" with a program...Where can i find some proper documentation on how to use gdal_cal.py.